# JQuery $.get() with asp.net gives 503 error on server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working on an application that is basically a registration page. I wanted to stop duplicate registration by checking existing email ids in the database. I used the JQuery $.get() method for querying to a page in the background and then get the result of existing or non exiting emails. The page runs perfect locally, but online, it returns `"503
Service Unavailable"` when the a duplicate email id is entered.

The jQuery method follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbEmail").change(function () {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var emailaddressVal = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbEmail").val()
        if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
            $("#msgbox").html('Invalid Email ID');
        return;
    }
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hidYorN").val("")
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
        $.get("scripts/email_availibility.aspx", { user_name: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
            if (data == 'no') 
            {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function () 
                {
                    $(this).html('This mail id is already registered!').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hidYorN").val("N");
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function ()  
                {
                    $(this).html('You are welcome to register!').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hidYorN").val("Y");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And my aspx page code (email_availibility.aspx):

```
string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString.ToString();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string data = "no";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(con);
    string user_name = Request.QueryString["user_name"];
    string strQury = "Select [EmailID] from [RegisterTable] where [EmailID]='" + user_name + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmds = new OleDbCommand(strQury, conn);
    OleDbDataReader dr;
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    dr = cmds.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        data = "no";
    }
    else
    {
        data = "yes";
    }
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
   Response.Write(data);
}
```

**I am not quite much used to JQuery, and just started with that, so please answer it simple**

Comment: ASP.NET + a 503 error means something very specific, that either the Application Pool servicing the application was stopped or has crashed. Are you sure the request isn't accidentally getting sent to a disabled site or virtual directory because of an error with the URL you provided to `$.get(0)`?

Comment: No, and I guess, this should not be the reason as well, as the request page exists in the same application.

Comment: Are you trying to call a page method? Then have you thought about the signature of the page method.

Comment: I think you should use web-method or http generic handler for this. And also rather than change you should call it on blur.

Comment: Sorry, but what does that mean? What I have done here is; By using $.get(), I passed `email_availibility.aspx?user_name=something`. When the onchange event of email texbox fires, the $.get() method will request the page `email_availibility.aspx?user_name=something` where `something` is obviously the email textbox value. The **email_availibility.aspx page** on its page load queries the database with that email, and then returns the results in form of "yes" or "no", through which `get()` method writes the result on the page. What did you mean by **signature of the page method**.

Comment: I don't think (not sure) without web-method attribute it can be called. Also you should avoid creating dynamic quries